# wildfly как изменить user.dir?

Tags: debian, wildfly

Wildfly поставлен на Debian. При попытке изменить значение user.dir через админку `/console/index.html#path` выдает
`{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "WFLYCTL0263: Path 'user.dir' is read-only; it cannot be modified"}`}
Как поправить?

Comment: user.dir - Это же рабочая директория, Директория, в которой запускается java. Наверное она не подлежит изменению. Да и не понятно, зачем её вообще пытаться менять?

Comment: я пытаюсь задеплоить spring boot+vaadin приложение на wildfly(debian). vaadin при старте пытается создать папку target/frontend по пути указанному в user.dir

Comment: Думаю стоит покурить мануал в поисках средств конфигурации ваадина. Не смотря на то, что такие штуки как vaadin странноватые, но они же (разработчики ваадина) знают в каком окружении работает их поделка и наверняка должны быть какие-то другие средства кроме user.dir